# UIImageView's size issue

Tags: ios, ios5, uiscrollview, ios6, uiimageview

kind friends.

I'm creating a universal page-based application for  an e-book targeting iOS 5.10or later. And I have some problems with it.

I wrote

```
        _pageData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"kkkn_0003.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"kkkn_0004.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"kkkn_0005.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"kkkn_0006.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"kkkn_0007.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"kkkn_0008.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"kkkn_0009.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"kkkn_0010.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"kkkn_0011.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"kkkn_0012.png"],
                 nil];
```

in the ModelController.m. All the images are same size, 102410 x 1536.

I use Storyboard, I first put an UIScrollView onto UIView, connected to DataViewController.h and named it scroll, then put an UIImageView also connected to DataViewController.h and named it imgv.

In DataViewController.m, I synthesized as following.

```
               @synthesize dataObject = _dataObject;
               @synthesize imgv = _imgv;
               @synthesize scroll = _scroll;
```

But some problems are here. So I wrote codes in viewWillAppear function as follows.

```
               NSLog( @"ImageView bounds %f, %f, %f, %f", _imgv.bounds.origin.x, _imgv.bounds.origin.y, _imgv.bounds.size.width, _imgv.bounds.size.height);
               NSLog( @"ImageView Frame %f, %f, %f, %f", _imgv.frame.origin.x, _imgv.frame.origin.y, _imgv.frame.size.width, _imgv.frame.size.height);
```

First, on iPhone4S running iOS 5.1, it shows
                   ImageView bounds 0.000000, 0.000000, 320.000000, 480.000000
                   ImageView Frame 0.000000, 34.000000, 320.000000, 480.000000
and works properly.

But on iPhone 5 running iOS 6.0.2, it shows the same value, so I have two margins at the top and bottom in light-yellow color. This is the first problem.

Second, on iPad2 running iOS 5.1, it shows

```
               ImageView bounds 0.000000, 0.000000, 688.000000, 944.000000
               ImageView Frame 0.000000, 0.000000, 688.000000, 944.000000
```

This means UIImageView is not in full screen and I can see its border on the screen. And also, the UIImageView is not justified to the center.

When running on iPad 4th gen running iOS 6.0.2, it shows

```
               ImageView bounds 0.000000, 0.000000, 768.000000, 1024.000000
               ImageView Frame 0.000000, 0.000000, 768.000000, 1024.000000
```

at the first page, but at the following pages, it shows

```
               ImageView bounds 0.000000, 0.000000, 688.000000, 944.000000
               ImageView Frame 0.000000, 0.000000, 688.000000, 944.000000
```

I did nothing but the UIImageView's size is different between the first page and other pages.
Also UIImageView is not in full screen mode so I see the border again.

Do you have any good solution?

Thanks for your help.
Masaru

Comment: This is probably a problem with the layout constraints. How did you set the size of the image views in IB? BTW, there's a function NSStringFromCGRect(), that you can use to log frames (or any other CGRect): NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(_imgv.bounds));

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. A  layout constraints? For iPad, I just put UIScrollView and UIImageView onto UIView, then they stretches to fit the screen. For iPhone, I did the same. Only difference is that I put those views for iPhone 3.5".

Comment: rdelmar, sorry, I forgot to say "Thank you" for telling me about NSStringFromCGRect function. That might be cool to code. Thanks again.